# animate element from center of view to its original position

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create one animation to move the elements from the center of current view to the original positions.

But **CSS** animation doesn't support toggling `display` property, so you will see the second rectangle doesn't move from the center in below picture (actually animated with `position:absolute`).

Is there any **Pure CSS** solution to reach the goal? Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Below is what I tried so far:

```css
.instruction-target {
  position: relative;
}
.highlight-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: solid 5px red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.float-highlight-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  animation-name: moving-to-target;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes moving-to-target {
  /* animate from: center of current view */
  from {
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* animate to: its original position */
  to {
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    //position: absolute; 
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 400px;border: solid 1px blue">
  <a style="position:fixed;top: 50vh; left: 50vw;">CENTER</a>
  <button class="instruction-target">
    Test1
    <span class="highlight-box float-highlight-box"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="instruction-target" style="margin-left: 400px">
    Test2
    <span class="highlight-box float-highlight-box"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use JavaScript or it needs to be CSS.

Comment: @TobyHarnish, OP said pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this with pure CSS, but it is necessary to use the CSS variables property.

> Here I have saved a [working example.](https://codepen.io/ionurboz/pen/rNWJZKG).

I am also adding a working snippet of code below so you can test it.

```css
:root {
  --target-offset: 0px;
}

.target-offset {
  --target-offset: 400px;
}

.fixed-center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.instruction-target {
  position: relative;
}
.highlight-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: solid 5px red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.float-highlight-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: var(--target-offset);
  animation-name: moving-to-target;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes moving-to-target {
  /* animate from: center of current view */
  from {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* animate to: its original position */
  to {
    top: 0px;
    left: var(--target-offset);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 400px;border: solid 1px blue">
  <a class="fixed-center">CENTER</a>
  <button class="instruction-target">
    Test1
    <span class="highlight-box float-highlight-box"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="instruction-target target-offset" style="margin-left: var(--target-offset)">
    Test2
    <span class="highlight-box float-highlight-box"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```