# CSS transform to center of screen and back

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm using Boostrap Vue to create tabs and each tab title can be suffixed by a "tick" icon.

I want to animate the icon to "pop out" from it's original position to the center of the screen and then return to the original position.

I have a transition pointing to the CSS for the animation but I'm not able to both animate to the center of the screen and animate back to the original position.

Here's a jsfiddle showing the problem - https://jsfiddle.net/8fs1g3yn/

The current state animates OK, but is not centered and depends on which tab you are in.

The animation position is "absolute" in order to show outside the scrollable tabs overflow and this allows use of the commented code on the 50% keyframe (left/top) to center it.
Unfortunately, since this is not a "transform" statement this happens suddenly at 50%.

Adding the same code at 0% keyframe shows the animation starting in the center, which is also acceptable, but then it suddenly jumps back to the original position after 50%.

In order to animate the return position the left/top can be added to the 100% keyframe, but then it animates to the wrong location.

Is there a way to define:

1. the outward animation to the center regardless of the starting point?

or

2. the return animation to the correct end point?

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <b-tabs nav-class="scrollable-tabs" active-nav-item-class="font-weight-bold" fill>
      <b-tab v-for="(tab, index) in tabs">
        <template #title>
          Tab {{ index + 1 }}
          <transition name="pop">
            <b-icon class="rounded-circle bg-success" v-if="tab.ok" variant="light" icon='check'></b-icon>
          </transition>
        </template>

        <button v-on:click="tab.ok=!tab.ok">Toggle</button>
      
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable-tabs {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.pop-enter-active {
  animation: pop-out 2s;
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes pop-out {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
/*    left: 50%;*/
/*    top: 50%;*/
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(10) translate(3vh, 5vh);
/*    transform: scale(10);*/
/*    left: 50%;*/
/*    top: 50%;*/
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
/*    left: 0%;*/
/*    top: 0%;*/
  }
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: [{'ok': false}, {'ok': false}, {'ok': false}, {'ok': false}, {'ok': false}]
      }
    },
  })
}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to make this go to the center automatically from the current position; you will need to calculate the necessary values.

Comment: OK, that's a shame...  I haven't looked at how to calculate this type of thing but presumably I need to use JS to calculate and inject the attributes?  I've got some more research to do then!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: [It is possible to do with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66392626/11151040), but you must use CSS variables.